# Getting Error 500 from Firestore request -

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Having issues with Firestore on NodeJS (functions). I have an API with the following:

```
export const getPost = (req: any, res: any): any => {
  let postData: any = {};
  postData.postId = req.params.postId;
  db.collection("posts").doc(`${req.params.postId}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).send({ error: "Post not found", success: false });
      }
      if( doc.data() && postData.postId)
      {
        postData = doc.data();
      postData.postId = req.params.postId;
      let commentsRef = db.collection("comments");
      return commentsRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc").where("postId", "==", req.params.postId).get();
      }

    })
    .then((data) => {

      if(data){
        postData.comments = [];
        data.forEach((doc: any): any => {
          postData.comments.push({ ...doc.data(), commentId: doc.id });
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).send({ data: postData, success: true });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ error: err, success: false });
    });
};
```

At the moment, there are no comments. There are posts. Yet I'm getting an Error .

`[Error: Request failed with status code 500]`

Am I missing something? Pretty confused if I'm honest.

Thanks

Comment: Any other error in the Firebase console?

Comment: Error 500 in firebase console. No reason why. Other functions in the API work perfectly well.

Comment: Can you add logging and check at which step does it fail in the function?

Comment: Will do. I have a feeling its failing at the comments collection step. I'll see if I can return just the post data without it to try and pinpoint a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Ah fixed!

My API was returning the error code, though not the error message content. I created a firestore log collection for error logs. On doing so, found that the error was as follows:

Thankfully, an easy fix, you just follow the link in the error and Firestore makes the index for you. Once I did that a few times (for each required index). It worked a treat.